# Property file not reflecting the modified changes using Apache Commons Configuration

Tags: java, properties, apache-commons, dynamic-programming, apache-config

I am trying to explore Apache commons configuration to dynamically load the property file and do modification in the file and save it.

I wrote a demo code for the same.

Code Snippet

```
    package ABC;


    import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
    import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
    import org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy;




    public class Prop {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            try {
URL propertiesURL = Prop.class.getResource("/d1.properties");

            if (propertiesURL == null) {
              System.out.println("null");
            }
String absolutePath=propertiesURL.getPath();
                PropertiesConfiguration pc = new PropertiesConfiguration(absolutePath);
                pc.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
                String s=(String)pc.getProperty("key_account_sales");
                System.out.println("s is " +  s);
                pc.setAutoSave(true);
                pc.setProperty("key_account_sales", "Dummy");
                pc.save();
                System.out.println("Modified as well");
                String sa=(String)pc.getProperty("key_account_sales");

                System.out.println("s is " +  sa);
            }catch(ConfigurationException ce)
            {
                ce.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Although when I run the code multiple times, the updated value for the property is being properly shown but the changes are not seen in the Property file.

I tried refreshing the entire workspace and the project but still the property file shows the previous entry whereas this code displays the updated entry in console.

Why my property file is not getting updated?

> Well I noticed that a new file with same name was formed inside bin
>   directory of my IDE workspace. This new file contains the required
>   changes.
>
> However I still want that the old file should be updated with the new
>   value and instead of creating a new file, it should update in the old
>   file itself.

My property file is located inside a Web Application package say

> Dem1

by the name of

> Prop1.prop

I want to read this property file from in another class say

> Reading.java

located inside another package

> Dem2

, do changes in this same property file and show it to another user.  It is a web application being deployed on an application server.

Even after using the absolute path in a simple file (main function) it is not reflecting the changes in the same file but updating it in new file.

I am doing a very slight mistake but can someone please help.

Using absolute path I am not able to make changes in the same property file in normal main method also. Please suggest.

> New file in bin directory is created instead of updating the same file
>   in src folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this using absolute paths. The `PropertiesConfiguration` class is finding your properties file somewhere on the classpath and only knows to write back to `"d1.properties"`; hence you have a file appearing in your bin directory.

The absolute path can be obtained by querying resources on the classpath. Something like the following:

```
URL propertiesURL = Prop.class.getResource("/d1.properties");
if (propertiesURL == null) {
  // uh-oh...
}

String absolutePath = propertiesURL.getPath();
// Now use absolutePath
```

Comment: Agreed.But ultimately it has to go inside web application where I think I would be forced to use relative path. In that case will it again create a new file or it will update the existing file. This is very crucial. Suppose a web application running on intranet and user wants to modify the key/value and I want to show the different user the modified key/value. So changes should happen only in 1 property file.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons Not a problem, see my edits above. Getting an absolute path for a classpath resource is not a problem.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Unfortunately, in my web application the property file is located inside a package in say pack1.org1 by the name Property1.prop. How do you suggest I go about loading this file, reading the property and updating the property in the same property file rather than creating a new property file. I think this   will definitely serve my purpose.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons Please edit your question to make it clear where exactly your property file is located.