# apache.commons.configuration Unable to load the configuration from the URL

Tags: apache, properties, load

For a project I'm working on I need to change some property values at run time and save them. Looking for a solution I found the apache commons configuration.

I have looked at some others topics solving my first problems but now, an error that says:

`org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to load the configuration from the URL file:/C:/Users/sensor/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HermanWijn/dist/run1776677076/HermanWijn.jar!/Database/DataProptester.properties`

Looking at this toppic: [Property file not reflecting the modified changes using Apache Commons Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457474/property-file-not-reflecting-the-modified-changes-using-apache-commons-configura)

My code should be working but for some reason I get an error.

The `JDBCWijnDAO` is a class in the same package as the properties file, Of course I want to do more than just load the prop file, but at the moment when creating the new propconfig, gives an error which I need to solve.

code:

```
URL resource = JDBCWijnDAO.class.getResource("DataProptester.properties");
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(resource.getPath());
```

Okay, i think i "know" what the problem is but I don't really know how to fix it, in the trace there is a:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Sensor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HermanWijn\dist\run1776677076\HermanWijn.jar!\Database\DataProptester.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I assume there is something wrong with the total path.

errors:

```
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to load the configuration from the URL file:/C:/Users/Sander/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HermanWijn/dist/run1776677076/HermanWijn.jar!/Database/DataProptester.properties
at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultFileSystem.getInputStream(DefaultFileSystem.java:86)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:323)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:261)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:238)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:158)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:253)
at hermanwijn.knophandlers.DataBestandLocatieSelectieHandler.handle(DataBestandLocatieSelectieHandler.java:49)
at hermanwijn.knophandlers.DataBestandLocatieSelectieHandler.handle(DataBestandLocatieSelectieHandler.java:29)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Sander\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HermanWijn\dist\run1776677076\HermanWijn.jar!\Database\DataProptester.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1035)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultFileSystem.getInputStream(DefaultFileSystem.java:82)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Sometimes when the same error happens on different conditions, correlating the line number with the source of Commons Configuration might give away the root cause.

Comment: The parent exception might give more information. See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/xref/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractFileConfiguration.html#269

Comment: I would post in a more neat manner but I can't find a way to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the problem was the package name was not included, it must be:
 URL resource = JDBCWijnDAO.class.getResource("/Database/DataProptester.properties");